# How to better separate the data points

Tags: machine-learning, python

I've got a particular data-set that looks like this in 2 dimensions. I have used the `StandardScaler` and `PCA` function in `python` to scale down the data from 50 dimensions to 2 dimensions.

I was wondering what kind of manipulations can i do, to better separate the red dots from the green dots so that i can classify them as one type of data?

Furthermore, i plan to use `MinMaxScaler` such that it will vary from [0,1] but i doubt that affects how it will appear on the graph.
[image]

Comment: Welcome! To me it looks like you might have used PCA on binary or multi-class data, and PCA is not very well suited to deal with these kinds of data. Theoretically PCA should do better with StandardScaling. I would consider just a simple classifier first (i.e. random forest) to check if data is separable, it might be difficult to do dimensionality reduction on your dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I apologise for the lack of info, but my initial data has 50 dimensions(variables) which are independent of each other.  Of which, 20 of them are physical quantities and 30 of them are binary values (0,1). I am still relatively new to machine-learning hence I am not quite sure what is the correct approach for these classification problems. May i know how does having something like a random forest algorithm help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is a type of classifier, but what you should do really depends on your goal and what you have. If you know what classes you have, then building the classifier might be just the way to go. If you dont know, then you might want to look at clustering approaches. It might be overwhelming at first, this diagram (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html) might be helpful, to just give an idea.

Comment: @boomkin Actually for my data, I only have 2 types of data, the Normal and the Attack. The model that i am trying to build right now is to be able to detect anomalies(Attacks) and i am using the `Negative Selection Algorithm` on my data, however I am obtaining poor results. I highly think its my method of pre-processing the data which leads to the points being very close to each other.