# What kind of model to use if the dataset are too similar?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am kinda stumped at a certain problem that I am currently having.

So lets say I have 2 different types of categorical data which labels `Normal State` and `Anomalous State`. Both data contains continuous data that are from 500 to 800kg.

What happens if the data from `Normal State` is extremely similar, if not identical to the `Anomalous State`? Does that mean that my training data is bad and I should just ignore it?

Comment: It simply means that the weights are similar between the two states, so you will not easily be able to predict the weight from the state, or vice versa.

Comment: @StephanKolassa would that mean this will run the risk of underfitting in my model because of the noise present? [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/416740/how-to-better-separate-the-data-points?noredirect=1#comment777710_416740) If you refer to my other post, i believe that is the problem I am facing right. Is there any way around it?

Comment: I think [How to know that your machine learning problem is hopeless?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/222179/1352) may be helpful.